# CustomNavigator within Column

Tags: flutter, dart, layout

I am trying to build an application with multiple pages, and a navigation bar that is always present. The navigation bar needs to scroll with the rest of the page. To do this, I have a Column in a singleChildScrollView, and within the Column is the navigation bar and a CustomNavigator to display each of the pages.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 100,
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
            ),
            CustomNavigator(
              key: mainNavigatorKey,
              initialRoute: Home.route,
              routes: {
                Home.route: (context) => Home(),
                PrivacyPolicy.route: (context) => PrivacyPolicy(),
              },
              pageRoute: PageRoutes.materialPageRoute,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

When I attempt to run this, I get a `_RenderTheatre object was given an infinite size during layout` error.

This is because the CustomNavigator uses an infinite height, and the Column defers to the child. I cannot set a static height of the CustomNavigator, as it will not handle pages of different lengths.

How can I implement this so that it doesn't have infinite height?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the CustomNavigator in a Expanded widget

Comment: @Neigaard, Yes I have, it results in this exception: ```RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.```

Comment: Ah yes it is inside a scrollview so that will not do, sorry. I do not know the CustomNavigator, is it this one https://pub.dev/packages/custom_navigator

Comment: Does wrapping a CustomNavigator in a SingleChildScrollView make sense? Does CustomNavigator not represent a whole page like the Home or other and including navigation at the top?

Comment: @Neigaard i think he want that `container` to be scrolled too.

Comment: @Neigaard, Yes, that is the dependency that I am using. Id like to have the navigation bar outside of the pages, so that animations can occur throughout page transitions. The navigation bar should be a constant part of the page.

Comment: @AlexCollette I think instead of `Column` using `Flex` and wrapping the `CustomNavigator` with `Expanded` would do the job.

Comment: @Adnankarim, using a expanded within the flex results in the following error:
```RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded```